# Swing - Launch browser and listen when user closes it

Tags: java, swing, browser, wait, processbuilder

I have this specific requirement.
If user clicks on a button in GUI, I need to launch browser.
I need to wait for two minutes. If user closes browser before two minutes, I need to launch window 'A'. If browser is kept open for more than two minutes, I need to launch window 'B'.

Presently I am able to launch browser window. But not able to listen when user closes it. Below is the snapshot of the code that I have written.

```
String url = "www.google.com";
Process browserProcess;
String commandLine = "rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + url;
String[] args = commandLine.split(" ");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

browserProcess = pb.start();
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(browserProcess.getErrorStream()));

String lineRead;
while ((lineRead = in.readLine()) != null) {
//do nothing
}

int exitVal;
System.out.println("Waiting...");
exitVal = browserProcess.waitFor();

System.out.println("Done");
```

Presently, waitFor() returns as soon as browser is launched. I need to wait till user closes the browser window. Any idea how it can be done?

Comment: You're forgetting about tabbed browsing.

Comment: Must easier to use Java Desktop API to launch a browser: `Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://www.google.com");`

Comment: I am sorry as I forgot to mention, I am writing code for java 1.5 only. So cant use desktop API :(

Comment: Of course you can, as Java Desktop API can be downloaded separatly.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you should take a look at [JDIC](https://jdic.dev.java.net/3), which I believe have been integrated into Java SE. Now, you have two solutions.

1. Either you use a browser integrated into your application, then you'll be able to see if user spent those two minutes watching the flies fly by. in this case, it'll be easy, by using a time counter, as an example, to see which frame to open.
2. Either you prefer (for maybe good reasons), to use an external web browser (Opera, Chromium, K-meleon, you name it). Then, you'll have to communicate with target web site to know when user closed frame. Indeed, it is possible for Javascript to see when page/tab is closed, and to send its own server a query to say "user 1258 just closed the window". Then, using client/server communication, your server will have to tell your application how much time the user looked at the window. Far more complicated, no ?

Comment: Huh.. yes it seems to be complicated may be because I am new to java. I need to open the link using default browser on the machine. I am not supposed to integrate it into application. I was reading somewhere that we can do it using batch script encapsulated with browser process and using threads.. Any idea about this?